# Checkbox won't stay checked on plugin settings page

Tags: php, wordpress

My checkbox field on a plugin page I wrote won't stay checked.  The data is being saved, but the checkbox does not reflect the current stored value (checked).

Here is my function code:

```
public function jo_checkbox_del_setting()
{
    echo "<input id='jo_checkbox_del' name='jo_plugin_options[jo_checkbox_del]' type='checkbox' value='{$this->options['jo_checkbox_del']}' />";
}
```

and the `add_settings_field` code:

```
add_settings_field('jo_checkbox_del', 'Hide Delete Button: ', array($this, 'jo_checkbox_del_setting'), __FILE__, 'jo_main_section');
```

[image]

as you can see in the picture, the value is 1 which is checked, but the checkbox never stays checked after refresh.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer to use WordPress [`checked()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) function with [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) <sup>(see the page for [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for usage examples)</sup>:

```
printf(
    '<input id="%1$s" name="jo_plugin_options[%1$s]" type="checkbox" %2$s />',
    'jo_checkbox_del',
    checked( isset( $this->options['jo_checkbox_del'] ), true, false )
);
```

Comment: `%1s` means the first argument to `printf`, so you do not have to repeat it in the argument list.

Comment: @GregLancaster, yes, as Niklas says. Normally, we use only `%s` without `OrderNumber$`. But if you want to use one of the values multiple times, or put them in a custom order, then the order number comes into place. The PHP manual has lots of examples.

Comment: Would this also work with an option button?  I reselected you as best answer, this is working like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

use `{checked($this->options['jo_checkbox_del']);}` inside the `<input>` element to return checked attribute if the option is set.

I would also recommend on using a hidden input with the same name attribute to handle the case when the option is not checked

```
public function jo_checkbox_del_setting() {

        echo "<input type='hidden' name='jo_plugin_options[jo_checkbox_del]' value='0' />";

        echo "<input id='jo_checkbox_del' name='jo_plugin_options[jo_checkbox_del]' type='checkbox' value='{$this->options['jo_checkbox_del']}'  {checked($this->options['jo_checkbox_del']);} />";   
}
```

Comment: the hidden input will make sure that a value is sent when the unchecked checkbox input is not sending anything as Niklas mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Use the `checked` attribute of the checkbox tag instead:

```
public function jo_checkbox_del_setting()
{
    $checked = ( (int)$this->options['jo_checkbox_del'] == 1 ) ? 'checked' : '';
    echo "<input id='jo_checkbox_del' name='jo_plugin_options[jo_checkbox_del]' type='checkbox' value='{$this->options['jo_checkbox_del']}' $checked />";
}
```

This is the [only way to have a pre-selected checkbox](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp). Setting the value to the stored value will not automatically trigger it to be set.

Also be aware that by default checkboxes in a form will not be sent along at all unless they are checked.

Comment: This solution fit like a glove, and is the ONLY one listed here that kept the checkbox checked. Thank you, thank you, thank you. If I could award you more points I would, especially for the reference - although I dont think the ref link really explains the reasoning behind why / how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that checkbox is checked and "tell" the HTML part of the page about that.

So, I suggest that you add `echo is_checkbox_checked() ? "checked" : "";` where `is_checkbox_checked()` is the function that checks whether `[jo_checkbox_del]` is `true` or `false`.

Your final code would look like this :

```
<?php
public function jo_checkbox_del_setting()
{ ?>
<input id='jo_checkbox_del' name='<?php echo jo_plugin_options[jo_checkbox_del]; ?>' type='checkbox' value='<?php echo {$this->options['jo_checkbox_del']}; ?>' <?php echo is_checkbox_checked() ? "checked" : ""; ?> />";
<?php } ?>
```